# php push in specific place

Tags: php

This is my base array:

```
$array = array(0 => 'value 1', 1 => 'value 2', 2 => 'value 3', 3 => 'value 4');
```

When I type:

```
array_push($array, 'New Value');
```

and my result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value 1
    [1] => value 2
    [2] => value 3
    [3] => value 4
    [4] => New Value
)
```

but I want result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value 1
    [1] => New Value
    [2] => value 2
    [3] => value 3
    [4] => value 4
)
```

Please Help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`array_splice($array, 1, 0, 'New Value');`

Second argument is the position in the array.

`array_splice()` is very useful when you want to inject items somewhere in the middle of an array (not at the beginning or to the end) or if you want to remove elements in the middle of an array.